# How do I build shelves on non-square (>90 degrees) walls?

Tags: shelving

I want to build shelves into an alcove, but the corners are not square. What is the best approach to this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Not square" can mean two different things: not a right-angle, or rounded.

If the walls are not at right angles, you can use a [T-bevel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_T_bevel) to measure the angle between the walls.  If you don't have a T-bevel, you can hold a piece of light cardboard against one wall and fold it so the crease is against the other, which you can use as a template for cutting the shelves.

If the corners are rounded, I'd use the cardboard again: estimate the radius of the corner, cut a quarter-circle of that radius, and check how well it fits into the corner.  If necessary, adjust the estimate and repeat.  Then use the quarter-circle as the template.

Comment: Make sure you do this at each height you plan on putting a shelf, just in case your walls aren't the same angle from floor to ceiling.

Comment: great tips, thanks guys. I have adjusted the question title to be more useful.